# Improving WMS screen rendering in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, rendering

I'm working with QGIS 3.22.7-Białowieża and I've added a WMS layer in my project through http://6ae9b70.online-server.cloud/geoserver/n2000/wms. But the rendering quality in the canvas screen is not as good as I'd like it to be, esp. in the labels: see the difference of the same WMS layer in QGIS (left) and in an online viewer (right)

[image]

I've tested that exporting the map as an image produces good results; I've also tested that this happens with other WMS layers as well; and I've searched through the QGIS documentantion, but without any success. Are there any options to improve the rendering quality in the canvas screen?

**Edit**: Following the suggestion made by @nmtoken, I've searched through the request info, and found this, that may be relevant

[image]

Comment: When I zoom in on your images, it appears to me that QGIS is providing *more* detail than the online example; I see more crenellations in the QGIS example, which makes me wonder if the online example was smoothing the image somewhat.  Or maybe my glasses lenses are scratched!  It would help if you would edit your post to include the WMS link, as well as the online viewer that you used.

Comment: could the issue be re-projection? Is your Qgis map in the same CRS as the WMS?

Comment: @StuSmith Edited, as requested

Comment: @Llaves No, it is not an issue of CRS, I've checked that already.

Comment: The online viewer seems to be a WMTS (or some other tiling scheme with repeated labels) can you capture the actual requests made between the two examples.

Comment: in QGIS: 1129 GET http://6ae9b70.online-server.cloud/geoserver/n2000/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=881675.5965862541925,4230318.001038855873,944437.2867558007129,4292566.007694197819&CRS=EPSG:25829&WIDTH=707&HEIGHT=701&LAYERS=zepa&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE

Comment: In viewer: http://6ae9b70.online-server.cloud/geoserver/n2000/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=zepa&format=image/png&WIDTH=756&HEIGHT=756&CRS=EPSG:25830&STYLES=&BBOX=420467.49528287334,4358981.255346725,449328.34751038835,4387842.107574239

Comment: The two example requests are using different CRS, which might make a slight difference.  Without a dpi (and related key values) value sent the dpi value (as set by the WMS standard) is approx 91 The standard says `the common pixel size is defined to be 0,28 mm × 0,28 mm`

Comment: But, having a look at the resulting images (clicking on the request links), both are ok. However, when visualizing it through the QGIS canvas, the rendering is quite poor, as seen in the image added in the edited question

Comment: I can see no difference in quality, between a request like `http://6ae9b70.online-server.cloud/geoserver/n2000/ows?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=658948.9253145017428,4374985.604385124519,705432.2335402575554,4406556.17891388014&CRS=EPSG:25829&WIDTH=880&HEIGHT=597&LAYERS=zepa&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE` in QGIS and in a browser, when QGIS map canvas is set to the same CRS (EPSG:25829).  I set DPI-Mode to off in the connection details

Comment: If on the other hand I set the canvas to a projection not supported by the service (say EPSG:4258), then the requested image is transformed in QGIS and the labelling and lines become distorted

Comment: Did you try changing resampling method (in layer styling, bottom): Nearest Neighbour, Bilinear, Cubic?